# Generating two numbers from an ID

Tags: logic

I have a table.  The table consists of an ID column ranging from 1 to 400.  Column 2 ranges from 1 to 10, and column 3 ranges from 1 to 40.  Here's my problem...

I need to mathematically resolve the correct column 2 and 3 values from column 1.

Example 1:

Col 1 is 40
Col 2 should be 1
Col 3 should be 40

Example 2:

Col 1 is 288
Col 2 should be 8
Col 3 should be 8

Example 3:
Col 1 is 52
Col 2 should be 2
Col 3 should be 12

I thought I could do this with simple division and modulus values, but it breaks at the first\last value in a range (e.g. col 2 is 0 and col 3 is 11 at 400 (should be 10/400), or col 2 is 0 and col 3 at 40 (should be 1/1)).  This should be super easy but I am brain farting all over the place.  Too much methane.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: You are right that division and modulo is the right way to go, but your insistence that everything starts at $1$ instead of at $0$ leads to off-by-one errors all over the place when trying the simple and obvious solutions.

Comment: @Arthur unfortunately, if I say "Base 10 numbering" to the original designers of this system, they get cross-eyed. :P

Comment: Do you know how to [make table with MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4240/290189)?

Comment: Col 2 is just the division of col 1 by 40 rounded to the next integer. Col 3 is then col 1 - 40 * (col 2 - 1).

Comment: Even though it's super ugly, I can produce col 3 by the following: ((input - 1) % 40) + 1

Comment: @N74 not rounded to the next integer, rounded down.

Comment: As Arthur wrote in his answer $x_2=\left\lceil\frac{x_1}{40}\right\rceil$, so the next integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above, had the columns gone from 0-399, 0-9 and 0-39 instead, then simple division and remainder would be exactly what you need. So, you can do all your calculations in that realm, then convert back afterwards, by first subtracting $1$ from every value that goes into a calculation, and then adding back $1$ at the end. (If you're afraid that your audience won't understand this, then you don't have to mention it; give them the formulas, and demonstrate that they work.)

If the value in column $1$ is $x_1$, then in column $2$ you want
$$
x_2=\left\lfloor\frac{x_1-1}{40}\right\rfloor +1=\left\lceil\frac{x_1}{40}\right\rceil
$$
and in column $3$ you would want 
$$
x_3=(x_1-1)-40(x_2-1) +1\\=x_1-40x_2+40
$$

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, as stated in my comments, that's what I ended up doing.  Super ugly, but it works.  Why there are "programmers" that can't operate in base10 is beyond me :D

Comment: could you tell me how to do the reverse of this?  Two numbers to one number.  Thanks.

Comment: That's easier, actually, and I think you can figure it out yourself, just from testing a few simple cases.

Comment: Hah I thought it would be, but I think I'm getting in my own way lol

Comment: Multiply one number by $40$, add the other number. This will be wrong by some constant (all numbers will be the same amount of wrong) because these numbers start at $1$ instead $0$. So you need to add or subtract that constant.

Comment: thanks, that got me going in the right direction.  I think I get a mental block when the math becomes graphical.  lol  

http://private.addohm.us/images/Undo_TrayID.png

http://private.addohm.us/images/Redo_TrayID.png